# Iterating through texts and putting them in one uitextview

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I get JSON response from the web and I successfully printing items out on the console using below code:

```
   for game in listOfRecentGames {
                            if let statInfoForTheGame = game["stats"] as? [String : String] {
                                var text = statInfoForTheGame["info"]
                            }
                        }
```

There are multiple number of games in `listOfRecentGames`. I get a string value of information for each game and I would like to show every of them in one UITextView. How can I achieve this? I was thinking about putting in array and printing out in UITextView but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You actually won't need an array to do that. You already have the `textView`'s existing text, so you just can append the new text to the existing one.

### Code

```
let listOfRecentgames = [
    ["stats": ["info": "Something1"]],
    ["stats": ["info": "Something2"]],
    ["stats": ["info": "Something3"]]
]

var textViewText = yourTextView.text
for game in listOfRecentgames {
    if let statInfoForTheGame = game["stats"] {
        if let text = statInfoForTheGame["info"] {
            textFieldText.appendContentsOf(" \(text)")
        }
    }
}

// Now you have the whole information from each game so just bind it to the textView
yourTextView.text = textViewText
```

### Playground output

[image]